# laravel get result from first table if second table did not match join condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a requirement where I need to get result from first table if the joined table where condition didn't satisfy.

I have two table food and food_translation,in food_translation table food names where saved in different languages and default name in food table.

if language condition didnt match in food_translation table,then need to get food default_name from food table

```
$food = DB::table('Program')
->leftJoin('Meals', 'Program.meal_id', '=', 'Meals.meals_id')
->leftJoin('Food', 'Meals.food_id', '=', 'Food.food_id')
->leftJoin('food_translation', 'food_translation.food_id', '=', 'Food.food_id')
->select('Food.food_id','Food.food_name','food_translation.food_ame','Food.default_name')
->where('food_translation.locale', '=', 'ar')->get();
```

Comment: See LEFT JOIN and COALESCE

Answer (score 2):

So when user's current lang. is arabic you want to show the food's arabic name but in case it doesn't exists show them the default name.In this scenario you can never use `where` clause because regardless of the join a `where` clause will eliminate any and all rows in the join result that don't match (even if using left joins).If no row in food_translation table has locale = 'ar' therefore in the join result too no row will have locale = 'ar' as a result everything gets eliminated.

What you need to do instead is add the locale ='ar'part in the join condition itself this will give you only those food_translation rows that have locale  = 'ar' **but without affecting the results of other table joins**.Then use [COALESCE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) (or [IFNULL()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp)) operator passing *food_translation.food_name* as 1st and *Food.food_name* as the 2nd parameter so if *food_translation.food_name* is not null it will be used otherwise *Food.food_name* used.

```
$food = DB::table('Program')
    ->leftJoin('Meals', 'Program.meal_id', '=', 'Meals.meals_id')
    ->leftJoin('Food', 'Meals.food_id', '=', 'Food.food_id')

        ->leftJoin('food_translation', function ($join) {
                $join->on('food_translation.food_id', '=', 'Food.food_id');
                $join->on('food_translation.locale', '=', 'ar');
        })

    ->select('Food.food_id','Food.food_name', DB::raw('COALESCE(food_translation.food_name,Food.default_name) as foodname')
    )->get();
```

All in all your raw sql might look like  this

```
SELECT  COALESCE(food_translation.food_name, Food.default_name) as foodname,Food.food_id  
from program

left join meals on meals.meals_id = program.meal_id

left join food on food.food_id = meals.meals_id

LEFT JOIN food_translation on ( food_translation.food_id = food.food_id and food_translation.locale = 'ar' )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
->orWhere('food_translation.locale', '=', 'ar')
```

use orWhere, then check result and take food_name.